# Ebean - OrderBy with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, playframework, ebean

Update : Solution found. Problem was somewhere else in my code.

I'm using Ebean with Play Framework and I'm stuck with a query witch as orderBy clause on two columns. The first column is a varchar and the second one is a datetime.

The problem is when I add the second column in the orderBy clause, I can't sort anymore on the first one.

I have tried with the Ebean query way and the RawSQL way but the problem is still here.

Here are the lines of code I have tried :

```
Ebean.createQuery(NavGav.class).where().in("account.itemState", Account.getActiveStates()).between("navGavDate", "2015-01-01 00:00:00", "2015-12-31 23:59:59").orderBy(orderBy + " " + sort + ", navGavDate").findPagingList(ITEM_BY_PAGE * 12);
```

RawSql :

```
select columns
from nav_gav t0 left outer join account t1 on t1.id = t0.account_id where t1.item_state in ('VALIDATED', 'PENDING_DEACTIVATION', 'UPDATED')
order By t0.nav_frequency desc , t0.nav_gav_date
```

The query works on phpMyAdmin but not in the application.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Update : Found the problem. It was somewhere else in my code. The above codes works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please try not to concatenate the `ordeyBy(column)` method. try this.

```
 Ebean.createQuery(NavGav.class)
                .where().in("account.itemState", Account.getActiveStates())
                .between("navGavDate", "2015-01-01 00:00:00", "2015-12-31 23:59:59")
                .orderBy(orderBy + " " + sort)
                .orderBy(navGavDate + " " + sort)
                .findPagingList(ITEM_BY_PAGE * 12);
```

Comment: Setting orderBy(...) twice will override the first orderBy(...).